# Is any possible for the report in pytest-html to be generate only when 1 test is fail?

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html-reporter

I got some tests to be executed and I want the report to be generated only if 1 of the tests are fail, right now I use this command:

```
pytest -v -s --html=report.html --self-contained-html --capture=tee-sys  -rx --verbose --maxfail=6  testCases/test_signup_0.py
```

but this command generates a report for passing tests too.

I tried to add --lf(list fails) but this command test only the fails tests.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From GitHub pytest-html discussion is not possible to that, this features will be added[image] in the 4.x version

[GitHub discussion](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html/discussions/528)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).